# OTP Hardware Compliant with OATH TOTP with php library

Tags: php, one-time-password

I am trying to use this **php library** [OTPHP](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/otphp) with a **c200 feitian OTP hardware token** (it states that is Compliant with **OATH TOTP**). The library works with google authentificator.

I can't figure out how to make it work with the hardware OTP.

They provided me with a `40 chars SEED` (in a .txt file) something like: `3C23CFBE4809287743B34E7A9B3C1237E8A7B3E2` (not the real seed). I used `$encoded = Base32::encode('')` and the library generates different codes than my token.

I really don't know what the seed format is, how should I encode it or what should I do to make it work with this library. Is this seed already encoded and I should decode it first?

I don't even know if the library should work with hardware tokens or only with software ones. 
The tokens work with [multiotp](https://github.com/multiOTP/multiotp) but I can't figure out how to add this library in a Larvel app.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same issue: we got **Feitian devices**, and had to set up their server side code.
None of the available implementations worked with them (neither php or java).

Solution: Feitian devices come with seeds in hexadecimal. First you have to decode the seed into raw binary, in PHP using the hex2bin(). That data is the correct input of the TOTP/HOTP functions.

Just for the future, i think you solved it already :)